# Can I Write And Read NFS Tag in the same Controller

Tags: swift

Can I Write And Read NFS Tags in the same controller. When I adding write and read functions only working writing. Can someone help me?

Write Function

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)

func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: 

[NFCNDEFTag]) {

}
```

Read Funtion

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession,didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    self.mainView.showErrorToast("Error while scanning NFC tag!")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    print(messages)
}
```